# Is awk a programming language or just a tool?

Tags: shell, awk

I have often seen people referencing "awk" as a programming language.According to my intuition all I understand about awk is that it is a tool used for some specific tasks.

So why would some people call it as a programming language?

Comment: How do you "define" a programming language? Is python a programming language?

Comment: Of course `Python` is programming language as is `awk`.

Comment: They'd call it a programming language because it is a programming language.  A number of the tools in general use include programming languages, notably Perl, Python, Ruby, Awk, Tcl/Tk, ...

Comment: You could say that since it is not very reasonable to code huge AWK scripts it is more a tool than a programming language, but this is only an opinion, not a definition.. (and some people did code 50KLOC awk scripts). In a certain sense, Python is more a programming language than a tool...

Comment: `awk` is a tool that uses a language called awk.

Answer (score 10):

`awk` is a programming language **and** it's designed for specific kind of tasks, these two things are not mutually exclusive. Much like `php` and `javascript` are also programming languages.

A tool lets you perform a single task or set of closely related tasks whereas with a programming language you can create any tool that is computationally possible.

`Awk` is a [Turing Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) language, compare it with the **tool** `grep`, you have variables, conditionals *(if,else,...)* ,repetition *(for,while,..)*, functions, ect. you can create an `awk` script to do whatever you may require but with `grep` you can only ever extract text from a file.  `Awk` is designed for text-based processing and still remains one of the best programming languages for this however you could write a compiler, interpreter, webserver, or anything else you wanted in `awk` - *but that doesn't mean you should.*

Answer (score 6):

Even though AWK is used in very restricted areas, it is **Turing Complete** and hence passes the test to qualify as a programming language.

Wikipedia defines `AWK` as follows. The `AWK` utility is an interpreted programming language typically used as a data extraction and reporting tool. But still it depends on individual users whether to call `AWK` simply a utility program or a programming language. But if you believe `AWK` is just a tool, then serious questions can be asked about the status of many so called languages like `HTML`, `XML`, etc. Also remember that the language `Perl` was heavily influenced by `AWK`.

Comment: XML and HTML are languages; they are not complete programming languages in the normal sense though (but neither are they 'tools' in any meaningful use of the term).